# Obtaining refresh_token through authentication api Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0

How to obtain refresh_token along with the access_token while reissuing the access_token through authentication api of auth0 using resource owner flow?

I have tried with the below code

```
DelegationRequestBase delegationRequest = new RefreshTokenDelegationRequest(["auth0:ClientId"], ["auth0:ClientId"],refreshToken);

  delegationRequest.Scope = "openid offline_access";
  delegationRequest.GrantType = "refresh_token";

  var res = cl.GetDelegationTokenAsync(delegationRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But I am getting below exception

> Auth0.Core.Exceptions.ApiException

with message ***refresh_token is not supported***

Is there any other interface or method to implement the same?

Comment: Can you clarify the following, the problem is that you wanted to obtain a new refresh token when refreshing an access token, but only an access token is returned? By OAuth rules, implementation can either issue a new refresh token when responding to an access token refresh request or only issue an access token. If only an access token is issued it probably signals that you can continue to use the refresh token you already have. **Why do you need a new refresh token?**

Comment: So if refresh token is expired what will happen to the response?will it send response with both access token and refresh token, or refresh token alone?

Comment: Refresh token expiration is again something that varies by implementation as the specification itself does not mandate it. Some implementation choose a really long expiration while in others the refresh token never expires, which it's the case for the Auth0 provider. They don't expire, but they can be revoked, check [the refresh tokens docs](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token) for more information.